# Multiple Worlds feature out of bounds

Tags: openlayers

When I have zoom level 0 in OL I can see multiple worlds. To me, it seems that only one of the worlds is the 'correct' world with correct coordinates. When I draw a point feature on the first world on the left I cannot translate it and the coordinates are not the real world coordinates. I can only translate the point when I draw it in the third world from the left. 
This seems kind of weird to me. Why has OL displayed multiple worlds when only one of them is correct? Can you do something that the coordinates of every world behave the same?

Here is a fiddle where you can test the behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/7cou2mLd/

**code snippet:**

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
    zoom: 0
  })
});

let vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
let vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

let drawPointInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  type: 'Point',
  source: vectorSource,
});
let translateInteraction = new ol.interaction.Translate();

map.addInteraction(drawPointInteraction);
map.addInteraction(translateInteraction);

drawPointInteraction.setActive(false);
translateInteraction.setActive(false);

function activateDraw() {
  drawPointInteraction.setActive(true);
  translateInteraction.setActive(false);
}

function activateTranslate() {
  drawPointInteraction.setActive(false);
  translateInteraction.setActive(true);
}
```

```css
.map {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
  <title>OpenLayers example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>My Map</h2>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <button onclick="activateDraw()">Draw</button>
  <button onclick="activateTranslate()">Translate</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a design feature https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/5128

However, you could put any out of bounds feature into the correct world before activating the translate interaction

```
function activateTranslate() {
  drawPointInteraction.setActive(false);

  vectorSource.forEachFeature(function(feature){
    var lon = ol.proj.transformExtent(feature.getGeometry().getExtent(),'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326')[0];
    var world = Math.floor((lon+180)/360);
    if (world != 0) {
      var geom = feature.getGeometry().clone().transform('EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326');
      geom.translate(-world*360, 0);
      feature.setGeometry(geom.transform('EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'));
    }
  });

  translateInteraction.setActive(true);
}
```

or more efficiently

```
function activateTranslate() {
  drawPointInteraction.setActive(false);

  vectorSource.forEachFeature(function(feature){
    var lon = ol.proj.transformExtent(feature.getGeometry().getExtent(),'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326')[0];
    var world = Math.floor((lon+180)/360);
    if (world != 0) {
      feature.getGeometry().translate(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-world*360, 0])[0],0);
    }
  });

  translateInteraction.setActive(true);
}
```